# Discussion on CSS override, preprocessors and better/cleaner code

Tags: css, sass, less

**TL;DR:** Lots of CSS overrides assigned via admin to frontend. Wondering if there’s a better way to solve the problem rather than ovverride every rule, every time.

---

Let’s say you’ve built a Wordpress website for a client of yours, a man of good manners and horrible taste called John. John can access his admin panel and create several boxes, each one with a different content. This is how it looks like on the frontend of his website:

```
<div class="box" id="box_01">Lorem...</div>
<div class="box" id="box_02">ipsum...</div>
<div class="box" id="box_03">dolor...</div>
<div class="box" id="box_04">sit...</div>
<div class="box" id="box_05">amet...</div>
```

At the same time, inside “style.css”, we find this single rule:

```
div.box { background-color: #eee; color: #333 }
```

Now user John, is really happy with your design, but would like to set the background of one of his boxes to electric blue and text color to black. Since he wants to be autonomous you provide your client with an administrative interface to do so, and proceed to implement the solution. Once you are done in the administrative area, you are now left with 2 PHP variables: $box_bg and $box_color. How and where are you going to ovverride the CSS previously stated inside of “style.css”?

The most straightforward solution, probably involves including this code somewhere in your page:

```
<style>

div#box_02 {

    background-color: <php echo $box_bg; ?>;
    color:  <php echo $box_color; ?>;

}

</style>
```

But is there a **better approach**?

For the sake of keeping things simple, this example features only two rules. Imagine instead of 2, there are 20 boxes, and for each you have to set background, color, size, position properties of the box itself and its own descendants. What happens is you end up with a gazillion of override lines in your HTML.

Which brings me again on the above question: is there a better and possible cleaner way? I thought, a PHP compiler for LESS or SCSS could be a good place to start – make it run once (every time a block/post is saved), and then rely on it’s cached output. 3 popular solutions seem to be https://github.com/leafo/scssphp, https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php and https://github.com/leafo/lessphp – while both LESS compilers seem to be have been discontinued, I wonder if it’s actually a good, practical and on top of everything secure, to use something like that on a live website.

What is your approach? What would you do?

Comment: For me your solution is the best approach, because this is dynamic variables

Comment: May be you can look at !default of SCSS ...You can actually have  variables lets say $color:red !default ,for a box and if at all you want a different color for the box you can override it accordingly